# EM algorithm example 7.2.19 of Casella & Berger Statistical Inference

Tags: expectation-maximization

I have been looking the Expectation Maximization example 7.2.19 in Casella & Berger (Statistical Inference) on Page 328. Here the $Y_i$ ~Poisson $(\beta\tau_i)$ and $X_i$ ~ Poisson ($\tau_i$)

[image]

I am just wondering if there is a mistake in the equation just at the top or beginning of P329. We have a term on P329 which is $\sum[\tau_i x_ilog \tau_i]$ which to me should have been $\sum [-\tau_i + x_ilog \tau_i]$. I see the same problem for the third term in the first set of parentheses.

[image]

Is there something I am missing here if it is correct. Please help!

Comment: Could you include the equations and some context in your question (by editing it), so that people do not have to check the book to understand what your question is about? Notice that by not doing this you limit the number of possible answerers to only those people who have the book at hand and I guess this limits your chances of getting answered.

Answer (score 1):

It's a typo, in $2^{nd}$ and $3^{rd}$ terms of the first parenthesis on page 329.

If you continue, you will notice that the $3^{rd}$ term is worked properly as

\begin{eqnarray}
-\tau_1\underbrace{\sum_{x_1=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\tau_1^{(r)}}(\tau_1^{(r)})^{x_1}}{x_1!}}_{\sum_{x_1=0}^{\infty}f_{X_1}(x_1)=1}
+log(\tau_1)
\color{blue}{\underbrace{\color{black}{\sum_{x_1=0}^\infty \frac{x_1\ e^{-\tau_1^{(r)}}(\tau_1^{(r)})^{x_1}}{x_1!}
}}_{\color{red}{\text{E}(X_1)=\tau_1^{(r)}, \text{ where } X_1 \sim Poisson(\tau_1^{(r)})}}} &=& -\tau_1+\tau_1^{(r)}log(\tau_1)
\end{eqnarray}

Which result is in (7.2.22).

Answer (score 0):

I also believe it's a typo. 
$\sum[\tau_i x_ilog \tau_i]$ should be  $\sum [-\tau_i + x_ilog \tau_i]$ .

Just like the authors said, the last equality grouped terms involving $\beta$ and $\tau_i$ and terms that do not involve them.

And the third term has the same problem. Otherwise, (7.2.22) doesn't work.

Maybe the authors have corrected them in the newest printing. I didn't see those typos in the errata. http://www.stat.ufl.edu/archived/casella/class/errata7.pdf

Comment: We are looking for high-quality answers. Could you provide arguments as to why there is/are a typo/s?

Comment: How can I say more ? Compare the terms in each equality. It doesn't involve any calculation, just move the terms.